# Output all nested array elements with recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So, let's consider we have such array:

```js
let array = ["Alex", 1,2,["Marta", 3], [[5, "Melman"]], 6];
```

I want to output all its elements with recursive function. 
My function is as follows:

```js
function recursive(arr){
    for(let f of arr){
        if(typeof(f)==="object"){
            return recursive(f);
        }
        else{
            return f;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work properly. So where is the problem ?

Comment: What sort of output are you looking for? Do you want to flatten the array, then print it, or print each item one by one, or what?

Comment: @CertainPerformance no, just print its elements on console one under another. Like ```"Alex", 1,2,"Marta",3 ...```

Comment: Maybe, you wanted to write this: `for (let f of arr) { if (typeof f === "object") recursive(f); else console.log(f); }`, in case you are only interested on log the elements on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to log the item to the console. And don't `return` from the `if`:

```
if (typeof f === "object") {
    recursive(f);
}

else {
    console.log(f);
}
```

(Also note that `typeof` is intended to be an operator, not a function.)

Comment: your solution worked for me, thank you ! But we have to delete ```return``` from else too.

Comment: Fixed @srvqaqa, any better?

Answer (score 0):

You end the function with the first [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Instead, you could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and yield the items or the inner array by calling the function.

```js
function* recursive (arr) {
    for (let f of arr) {
        if (Array.isArray(f)) yield* recursive(f);
        else yield f;
    }
}

let array = ["Alex", 1, 2, ["Marta", 3], [[5, "Melman"]], 6];

console.log(...recursive(array));
```

Comment: thank you, but I've never seen neither ```*``` sign with function and ```yield``` keyword in Javascript. I couldn't understand your code.